# Is changing of width and height of smart object image by using free transform OR resizing of the image the same things?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, image-quality, image-processing

I'm not very good in Photoshop tools,   can someone help me to understand;

Is changing of width and height of smart object image by using free transform, OR resizing the image,  the same thing?

If I change the width and height of smart object image with free transform in Photoshop  will it automatically rebuild the image  with a new number of pixels  just like if I   resize the image with  the resize image function in Photoshop?

Comment: Maybe making two copies of a picture, trying one technique on each and then exporting might show any differences.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick check that I have made:

- When resizing an image, with the image>image size menu option, you
  actually change the canvas size WITH the image size.
- However, when using free transform, you change JUST THE IMAGE.

In both cases, if the image is a smart object, you retain the original image resolution and information.
I made sure of the last point by simply using the menu image size dialog to minify an 4000x4000 image to a 200x200 and back, and lost no information.

Bottom line, both are valid, depending on what you want to do with the rest of the canvas.